# Blank screen on first boot, screen appears in second boot

Tags: hdmi, display, config.txt

I am using Raspberry pi 2 with kernel version `3.18.11-v7+` and HDMI to VGA converter to connect to Monitor.

Every time I disconnect the power supply and boot, blank screen appears. When I reboot, screen appears.

Steps tried so far:

1. Enabled boot to desktop in `sudo raspi-config`. After setting boot
   to desktop, raspberry pi auto reboots and screen appears. But when
   ever I shutdown and boot again, no screen on display.
2. Edited `/boot/config.txt` file:

   - uncommented `hdmi_safe=1` and `disable_overscan=1`. Screen appears after every shutdown but with very low resolution.
   - commented `hdmi_safe=1` and uncommented `hdmi_group=2` and `hdmi_mode=86` to force into hdmi mode. The resolution got corrected after reboot but after shutdown boot, no screen appears.
   - uncommented `hdmi_safe=1` and uncommented `hdmi_group=2` and `hdmi_mode=86` to force into hdmi mode. Screen appears after every shutdown but with very low resolution.

Any workaround to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_safe), setting `hdmi_safe=1` is the equivalent of setting a bunch of things including a low resolution `hdmi_mode`.  You might try re-ordering the lines to see if you can override that with a mode set before or after (I think usually lines later in `config.txt` take precedence, but I have not experimented extensively with that).

Anyway, looking at the list of things invoked by `hdmi_safe=1`, you could instead try:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
config_hdmi_boost=4
```